# Is there a way to query keycloak user on user attributes?

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I am planning to use keycloak as Identity provider for one of my project. I wanted to extend the user information by adding user attributes, but the problem is I also want to be able to query based on that attribute.

Did some research but couldn't find one yet.

I am using `keycloak-admin` nodejs package.

Comment: Is this still relevant? I just query all users with JavaScript and filter by attributes then. 

localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the package wraps the Keycloak Admin API and at [the users resource](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) there is no queryParameter to query user attributes, I guess you have to fetch all users and filter yourself.